# Ring homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$. Is this condition necessary?

Tags: ring-theory

I am reading in some text that given two rings unity say $R$ and $K$. Let $\phi:R \rightarrow K$ be a ring homomorphism. Is the condition $\phi(1_R)=1_K$ needed to define ring homomorphism?

Comment: For rings with unity, yes.

Comment: If your rings are defined with a unity, then yes, I guess you have to ask that $\phi(1)=1$ for the definition to be consistent.

Comment: For rings-with-unity, yes; for rings, no. But some books call a ring what I call a ring-with-unity.

Comment: If $\phi(1_R)\ne 1_K$, then $\phi$ may still be a homomorphism of *rings* $R$, $K$, but it won't be a homomorphism of *rings with unity* $R$, $K$.

Answer (score 2):

By way of analogy, note that we *do not* have to axiomatize $\phi(0_R) = 0_K$, because it follows from the existence of additive inverses in a ring. Specifically, for all $x \in R$, we have
$\phi(0_R) = \phi(0_R + 0_R) = \phi(0_R) + \phi(0_R)$, and then add $-\phi(0_R)$ to both sides to get $\phi(0_R) = 0_K$.

However, we are not guaranteed the existence of multiplicative inverses. Therefore, if we want $\phi$ to preserve the unity component of $R$'s structure, then it has to be built into the definitions.